# How to identify the caller function name in an AJAX or XMLHttpRequest call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance, instrumentation

I am trying to find out how to identify the function name which initiated the Ajax call programmatically using JavaScript or jQuery for an existing code base.

I am working on the instrumentation of an existing large code base and hence trying to identify the function name which correlates with the AJAX requests. So, there is already a lot of code and modifying each method doesn't seem to be the best approach. So, I am trying to think about a generic approach which can work for all the methods. The code already has a generic wrapper around the AJAX call, so I can hook into the entry and exit points of the method.

For e.g. in below code, in the `always` function, I need to know the initiator function name or the call stack.

```js
function ajaxWrapper(){
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" )
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
   // TODO: Who Initiated the call ?
  });
}

function initiator1(){
 initiator2();
}

function initiator2(){
 ajaxWrapper();
}

initiator1();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**What have I tried?**

1. I know one approach is using setting the custom headers in the `beforeSend` method and the always callback receives the `jqXHR` object as the parameter. But this doesn't seem to be suitable approach as I can't modify all the functions to send the method name as a parameter.
2. `arguments.callee.caller` approach, but it doesn't seem to work in case of the Asynchronous methods. Also, this feature seems to be deprecated because of performance and security reasons.

Note: I am not looking this information for debugging purpose. I am already aware of the Async call stack, Initiator and console.trace solutions available in developers tool.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to generate the call stack inside your wrapper, because up to that point you are in a sync function call chain.

```
var err = new Error();
var stack = err.stack;
```

And use it later in the callback, because it's available as part of a higher scope. (Scopes don't care about async.)

You'll need to do some parsing (browser specific unfortunately) on that call stack. I don't know what you intend to do with the initiator, but you may want to keep all the chain, not just the first one.

Also note that this technique is [unreliable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack) and you shouldn't use it for anything critical.

```js
function ajaxWrapper(){
var err = new Error();
var stack = err.stack;
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1" )
  .done(function() {
    console.log( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( "complete" );
    // TODO: Who Initiated the call ?
    console.log(stack);
  });
}

function initiator1(){
 initiator2();
}

function initiator2(){
 ajaxWrapper();
}

initiator1();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: +1 Thanks Alin, do you know any performance implication of creating a lot of Error objects as i need to add this code to the generic ajax wrapper? And is it good practice to create a Error object when there is no error functionally or technically?

Comment: @Agalo The Error object overhead I think is negligible compared with the HTTP request overhead they are attached to.